# populate select box with data from mysqltable

Tags: php

How to populate select box with data from mysql table, and then move that value from one page to another.
I did a small coding, and i was able to get all the values from table, but i cant move those value to other page.

```
$query1="SELECT  * FROM seat_no WHERE seatno NOT IN(SELECT seatno FROM check_in_desk)";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1);

<select name="txt_seatno">
 <?php

while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
echo "<option value=$nt[id]>$nt[seatno]</option>";
}
</select>
?>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to send all the values to another page? Or would a user select a value from your select box and that's what you would like to send to another page?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just lookup the values on the page where you need them?  If not, you could pass the data as a GET or POST variable, and then use this to generate the select box options on the new page.

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways I can think of;

1) append the value to the url, so it'd be;

`echo '<a href="page.php?id=' . $nt[id] . '">' . $nt[seatno] . '</a>';`

and in the receiving page, you'd put;

`$id = (int) $_GET['id'];`

2) Or you could simply use this;
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select2

(dropdown menu)

(btw; your < /select> should come **after** ?>)